# Comparar valores usando SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Me encontro na seguinte situação da imagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso via sql comparar o valor do imóvel com o valor do filtro mínimo e máximo mas devido os pontos e vírgulas não obtenho resultados. Como posso solucionar esse problema ?

Comment: Qual o tipo do campo onde você armazena o valor?

Comment: Você já tem um trecho de código pronto ?. Se sim poste aí. O que basicamente tem que ser feito é o seguinte:. Uma função em javascript fica escutando as alterações no campo select. Quanto isso acorrer ela fara uma requisição para um script em php que fara a consulta no banco de dados.

Comment: O certo a fazer é armazenar os valores no banco de dados sem essa formatação que usamos (R$, vírgula, ponto*). O valor deve ser armazenado em uma coluna do tipo decimal. Daí vc vai formatar esse valor direto no PHP e/ou javascript. *Lembrando que o mysql trata ponto como separador decimal. Logo, R$ 10,99 deve ser armazenado simplesmente como 10.99.

Comment: É uma grande encrenca armazenar valores formatados como esse em banco de dados. Considere isso para rever sua lógica de implementação. Se for algo legado boa sorte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o Replace do MySQL

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php

```
SELECT <CAMPOS> FROM <TABELA>
WHERE CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(CAMPO, '.', ''),',','.') as DECIMAL(10,2)) 
       BETWEEN MINIMO AND MAXIMO
```